# Oracle OS authentication authentication

Tags: oracle, authentication

I have problem logging in to one of the accounts in our database. The situation is like this.

The user has already logged in to his account environment on Linux, for example from his personal account

```
su - projectA
```

The user tries to run SQL*Plus using

```
[projectA@myDB2]$ sqlplus /
```

We are getting the message:

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password: logon denied

I ran this command below and it has a missing prefix.

```
SQL> SHOW PARAMETER os_authent_prefix
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
os_authent_prefix                    string      
SQL>
```

How do I set a prefix on `os_authent_prefix`?

Comment: How was the database account created?

Comment: It's fine for the prefix to be null. You probably want either `CREATE` or `ALTER USER projectA IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY`. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/admnauth.htm#sthref1240

Comment: If you really want to set the prefix though, I'd do `alter system set OS_AUTHENT_PREFIX='your_prefix_here' scope=spfile;` and then bounce the database.

Comment: Alex, the database was already created from myDB1 and rmyDB2 is a copy from myDB1. I simply use rman.

Comment: @JustinC - I was referring to the user's account in the database, not the database itself.

Comment: kfinity, thanks for the idea. I attempted to use that same command prior of posting this message. However, I am still trying to find any alternative idea. The user later asked me not to run it since he decided to run his development script on other db server. We tried not to recreate the projectA schema since it has many external tables link to it.  If something happened, I know that I could simply refresh it back again using rman but I will put this on hold until the senior db admin is back. I am still new to this.

Comment: Hi Alex, the account was created by Linux admin. On the database side, it was created using --> create user ops$projectA identified externally; I am not sure why suddenly it breaks. The senior DB admin was on break for a week and I am stuck with  this without much instruction (I am learning on the go).

Comment: I will check the link ALTER USER projectA IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY from docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/. Thank you to both of you. If nothing works out at least I learned something enw.

Comment: Do I need to put  'ops$' or just ops$ below? For some reason the user asked me not to change anything now. 
alter system set os_authent_prefix = ops$ scope = spfile;

Comment: If the DB account was created as `ops$projectA` then the `OS_AUTHENT_PREFIX` needs to be `OP$S`. With no prefix set the account name should not have that prefix either. Either is valid but you need to decide which way to go; which might be based on the old DB or other accounts that do currently work. [Read more in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#DBSEG-GUID-2975A29E-FF3C-4A9C-9E0D-AB28C5DF4462).

Answer (score 1):

You're allowed to have no value set for `OS_AUTHENT_PREFIX`, but if you do then the database account needs to be the same as the operating system account - i.e. `projectA` instead of `OPS$projectA`.

If you do want the account to have the `OPS$` prefix then the initialisation parameter has to match. You can set it as @kfinity said in a comment:

```
alter system set OS_AUTHENT_PREFIX='OPS$' scope=spfile;
```

followed by a DB bounce. But as that is the default value (still, I think!) it's likely someone has intentionally cleared it, so proceed with caution.

The main thing is to be consistent. If you have other user accounts with `OPS$` then you probably should have it set (and you can check the old DB you mentioned to see if the users and settings are the same). If you don't have any others then you need to verify whether any of the un-prefixed account names are identified externally via the `dba_users.authentication_type` column. If there are any then changing the initialisation parameter would break those.

[Read more in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#DBSEG-GUID-2975A29E-FF3C-4A9C-9E0D-AB28C5DF4462):

Comment: Thank you for all our help. The senior DB confirmed that it is the correct statement to run on sqlplus like you all commented here. Actually I wanted to run that statement too but the Java developer worried that it might messed up the links to the external tables (text files). To tell the truth I am coming from a Java/Python background but taken up this job as junior DB. So there is a lot to learn here. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm not sure how changing that could affect external tables, which use DB directory objects and rely on OS permissions - authentication of DB users doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: I agree with you but the Java Developers who was working on that box that wasn't sure at the time. It was just the OS authentication with prefix on or no prefix string. At least we learned something new especially me which is a good thing for everybody. Again, thank you Alex for your time. I really do appreciate for your help as well as kfinity.